# Is there a way in PHP to access compressed RTF and output RTF code

Tags: php, rtf

Is there a way in PHP to access compressed RTF and ouput RTF code to the browser?

I have a text column in SQL and I would like to extract the RTF from it - I have managed to output the data as 0x1F8B

I believe this data is compressed RTF - http://www.freeutils.net/source/jtnef/rtfcompressed.jsp

Using [MS-OXRTFCP]: Rich Text Format (RTF) Compression Algorithm http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc463890%28v=exchg.80%29

**Sample data :**

```
0x1F8B0800000000000000654E316EC3300CEC5CA07FE0D6AD909D1628E0A1C8D01F74E422CB94CD46A11C4A6E5018F97B6967EC72381EC9BB5B516B6CD04BE11DC23C36ED5B8B03C5E8364C5EC6C61D0E2BC62CB5F6C988C358AE5C0AC6592F2DC630792D541D1C957DEA6E76D260144EFF57B7A7C715434E59CD0A3A541A1C8E4A240EFBB490EBEC027F98AE2796E11597D0E0EC75C013D1BC8360F1EF0EC316B115695BF89A08CE390B70816ABC571EA74AA542EEBF295460D975642B069F5EEBF45C6CB27707E5F4FBB14558EC1D83D9EEEC28D9BE142E8B59719697BB6C051FFE00D09796A337010000
```

And this looks like what I want but its in VB http://www.vbforums.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=87371&d=1326754610

Comment: As long as "compressed RTF" has lossless compression (which would *make* sense), there is a way to access compressed RTF and output it as uncompressed RTF. The way is to uncompress it. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I tried gzdeflate and got U‘¹ D1D[ÌaBsõ_ÒòÃ%ABˆy3àÜ€¥Â}P;ÏÈNÉ6 ¥¯¼Pé6<Ì[€cÜL”áœÅú“Ÿ¶ÞquµN£s±Ó#$548±’Ní’XŽ“Ò÷(oKMÅ‚¦HÝã2š~o¹¯%á¥ŠÓP¥0§ÆÂt±êU7-R@æž{–†Â‡[|¥ßy»ÿh~ÄÐÁ@6¾d®Ë'në`EñF. öìpCŠÝQ—˜ënöqƒ‹ú"Å°Ÿñ[1êŽ!V(7Q¦õ‘oÌ²fƒÌÀZ†—YävbÝSÞÝI·|ãÚ37 ]7ÚMg¾¼ïü>ø

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your data sample is gzipped data, use [`gzdecode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php) to decode it. You'll need to pass a binary string not the hex string supplied(use [`hex2bin`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php) or [`pack`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) to convert)

```
if (!function_exists(hex2bin)){
    function hex2bin($hexStr){
        return pack('H*', $hexStr);
    }
}
$rtf = gzdecode(hex2bin('1F8B0800000000000000654E316EC3300CEC5CA07FE0D6AD909D1628E0A1C8D01F74E422CB94CD46A11C4A6E5018F97B6967EC72381EC9BB5B516B6CD04BE11DC23C36ED5B8B03C5E8364C5EC6C61D0E2BC62CB5F6C988C358AE5C0AC6592F2DC630792D541D1C957DEA6E76D260144EFF57B7A7C715434E59CD0A3A541A1C8E4A240EFBB490EBEC027F98AE2796E11597D0E0EC75C013D1BC8360F1EF0EC316B115695BF89A08CE390B70816ABC571EA74AA542EEBF295460D975642B069F5EEBF45C6CB27707E5F4FBB14558EC1D83D9EEEC28D9BE142E8B59719697BB6C051FFE00D09796A337010000'));
```

Here is the raw data.

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset0 Arial;}{\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Arial;}}
{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue0;}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\keep\keepn\sa80\cf1\f0\fs22 The moon is the brightest object in the \i\f1 Earth's \i0\f0 sky?\par
\par
\cf0\par
Another question.\par
}
```

And this is the rendered text.

> The moon is the brightest object in the *Earth's* sky?
>
> Another question.

I'm not sure if you only want the raw rtf or rendered, take a look at [Free (preferably) PHP RTF to HTML converter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047411/free-preferably-php-rtf-to-html-converter) if you want the rtf in html.

Comment: Great going. Hope you get the bounty :)

Comment: OMG amazing! - the bounty has disappeared on this question - I want to award to you - can I reassign?

Answer (score 6):

I can't tell you if

```
0x1F8B0800000000000000654E316EC3300CEC5CA07FE0D6AD909D1628E0A1C8D01F74E422CB94CD46A11C4A6E5018F97B6967EC72381EC9BB5B516B6CD04BE11DC23C36ED5B8B03C5E8364C5EC6C61D0E2BC62CB5F6C988C358AE5C0AC6592F2DC630792D541D1C957DEA6E76D260144EFF57B7A7C715434E59CD0A3A541A1C8E4A240EFBB490EBEC027F98AE2796E11597D0E0EC75C013D1BC8360F1EF0EC316B115695BF89A08CE390B70816ABC571EA74AA542EEBF295460D975642B069F5EEBF45C6CB27707E5F4FBB14558EC1D83D9EEEC28D9BE142E8B59719697BB6C051FFE00D09796A337010000
```

is actually compressed RTF data. But if so, the [Zarafa's PHP MAPI Extension](http://developer.zarafa.com/php-ext/) offers a function to decompress it: [`mapi_decompressrtf()`](http://developer.zarafa.com/php-ext/ref-Zarafa-Text-Functions.html#mapi_decompressrtf).

Comment: I saw that but - didnt see a download for it?

Comment: You find it here: https://git.zarafa.com/zcp/zcp/trees/master/php-ext / `git://git.zarafa.com/zcp/zcp.git`

Comment: @Rob: Are you looking for a non-binary solution to your problem? How much time can you invest for a PHP port?

Comment: I am looking for a non-binary solution (web site accessing an existing DB) - the solution is an innovation so dont have much backing at the moment but loads of time (no $$) - but if we did go ahead it could be very good

Comment: I'd start with a port of that decompress stream thingy. Should be possible to port it to PHP and solve the issue for you. Ideally create a github repro and start with writing tests. Would be good to have some testdata as well.