# Sending RTF as email php

Tags: php, email, rtf, phpmailer

I've got a field that contains an RTF document (stored as text) that I want to use as a body of an email. Is there any way of sending it as the body of the email using PHPMailer?

Comment: Convert it to text or html. Or send it as an attachement. Because email clients usually show text or html and sometimes audio/video files. But rarely other formats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to convert rtf to html. Use this: [Free (preferably) PHP RTF to HTML converter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047411/free-preferably-php-rtf-to-html-converter)

then send the html text in email