# PHP - Syntax of exec() function to call another php file

Tags: php, converters, rtf

This question is in reference to:

[Free (preferably) PHP RTF to HTML converter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047411/free-preferably-php-rtf-to-html-converter)

I'm trying to execute that last line of code in my php:

```
exec(rtf2htm file.rtf file.html)
```

I understand what parameters need to go within the parentheses, I just do not know how to write it.  I've looked at multiple examples along with the php documentation and still I remain confused, so could someone show me how it is written?  `rtf2htm` refers to a PHP file which converts RTF to HTML.

Ultimately what I am trying to do is convert the content of numerous RTF docs to HTML, maintaining the formatting, while not creating tags such as`<head>` or `<body>` which programs like Word or TextEdit generate when converting to HTML.

Comment: exec("rtf2htm file.rtf file.html");

Comment: @Orangepill `rtf2htm` alone gives me the error `not recognized as internal or external command.`  My environment may be set up wrong, I don't know since I'm relatively new to coding.  `rtf2htm\rtf2tm.php` does work though but only opens it in it's associated app instead of converting docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rtf2htm is not a php script, it is a program installed on the server. exec() is used to call external applications.

EDIT: After looking up this script, it seems that it is indeed a php script. But it has been coded to be usable from the command line only.

This should work:

```
<?php

exec('php /path/to/rtf2htm /path/to/source.rtf /path/to/output.html');

?>
```

Comment: `php` is giving me the error `not recognized as internal or external command.` Thanks for clarifying the code though, since `path/to/rtf2htm` is now opening the php file, but it only opens in its associated application (my IDE) instead of converting the docs.

Comment: replace php with the full path to the php executable, so you'd get `exec('/path/to/php /path/to/rtf2htm /path/to/source.rtf /path/to/output.html');` or `exec('/path/to/php.exe /path/to/rtf2htm /path/to/source.rtf /path/to/output.html');` on windows.

Comment: `exec('Drive:/path/to/php.exe')` is allowing it to work, yet the scripts intended affect is not working.  Something either is not being inputted correctly or there is a bug somewhere within it.  Thanks for the help though.  I'll post a solution if I find one.