# Convert RTF encoded string to HTML string

Tags: html, string, html-parsing, rtf

How can I convert RTF encoded string like one below, to an HTML string, without using RichTextBox control. I have a MVC app, which converts HTML string to PDF and now some data is provided as rtf encoded string which needs to be converted into HTML before creating the PDF. I checked utilities like Aspose.Words, but they convert a .rtf doc to .html

\b Skin Allergy Tests (Positive reactions are reported as the wheal size in mm)\b0\par \par \b Foods\b0 \b Pollens\b0 \b Moulds\b0\par Cod 0 Acacia 0 Alt. tenuis NP\par Cow's milk 0 Bahia grass 0 Asp. 
fumigatus NP\par Egg 0 Eucalyptus NP Hormodendrum NP\par Peanut 0 Pine mix NP

Please advice. Thanks

Comment: Replace \b with <b> and </b>; \par becomes </p><p>, etc

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047411/free-preferably-php-rtf-to-html-converter

Comment: Musa, that is a PHP utility. I am after .NET